# Время на получение Dev лицензии

Tags: ios

День добрый, захотелось поучиться по программировать на iPhone. Я хочу приложения тестировать на телефоне, сколько времени со времени оплаты занимает получение сертификата и т.д ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Точно не больше недели)

Comment: ну если не больше недели, то отличненько =) спасибо